# javascript - 10000 ajax запросов в браузере

Tags: javascript, ajax

У меня есть скрипт (не *Nodejs*), в котором очень много *ajax* запросов. Всё это неплохо работает, за исключением того, что после 3000 браузер крашится. (необязательно после 3000. это для примера.)

И у меня вопрос. Возможно ли, как-то запустить скрипт вне браузера? А еще лучше запустить в браузере, но выполнять вне браузера.

Что я уже делал :

1. Использовать `async:false`.
   Всё прекрасно работает, но интерфейс страницы фризится, а запросы выполняются достаточно медленно. Так же я думаю, что при использовании колбэков вместо `async:false` выполнение скрипта останется прежним. Интерфейс возможно останется рабочим, но скорость работы останется такая же и это существенно утяжелит мне написание кода.
2. Использование *Headless browser*. Я попытался использовать движок *Rhino* в консоли под *Windows*. Переписал код под это дело, но он начал выдавать такое количество ошибок (причем достаточно несущественных при выполнении кода в браузере), что после, где-то, 15 я махнул на этот метод рукой. *Rhino* я использовал вместе с *Envjs* и *Jquery*).
3. Запаковка *Javascript* в *Windows* приложение. Попробовал, но это совсем не то.

Структура кода сейчас выглядит примерно так :

```
$.ajax({
    url: "ajax/example.php",
    success: function(data){
        $.ajax({
            url: "example.php",
            success: function(data){
        });
    },
    complete: function(){
        $.ajax({
            url: "example.php",
            success: function(data){
        });
    }
);
```

Переписывать код на *Nodejs* или любой другой язык я не намерен. А и чуть не забыл, браузер *Firefox* (может нужно). Система довольно слабая. Ошибка, выдаваемая при краше браузера, связана с *jquery.js* соответственно.

Comment: а что за ошибка при краше браузера, полностью напишите? `связана с jquery.js` это никакой информации не дает. И по теме, зачем вы используете такое количество запросов, какова их роль?

Comment: Сейчас сымитировать ошибку я не могу, так как нахожусь не за своим компьютером. Но я на 100% уверен что краш происходит только по причине огромного количества запросов. А такое количество использую в получении информации для своего бота. Это тоже не суть важно. Важно то, что запросов очень-очень много, и порядка 4 в секунду при нынешнем коде.

Comment: Я просто пытаюсь найти альтернативу async:false/колбекам. И допустим стандартизировать один ajax запрос, запихнуть в одну функцию с колбэком, я тоже не могу. Потому, что у меня 5 блоков функций с запросами. По 2-3 вложенных запроса в каждом. И каждый запрос написан под свои нужды. Возможно я не лучшим образом описал вопрос, за это простите. Но главный вопрос как что ли замедлить отправку запросов. (setTimeOut думаю предлагать не нужно)

Comment: 3000 синхронных запросов?

Comment: Сейчас это работает как 10000+ асинхронных запросов с псевдосинхронностью за счет success/complete структуры. (так как complete запускается после success, то я успеваю получить нужную информацию и перенаправить куда мне надо)

Comment: @elpax как это возможно, что на каждый ответ ajax'a вам нужно ещё по нескольку ajax отправлять обратно, неужели невозможно их объединить (по любому возможно)? А так тогда уж проще сокеты использовать, чтобы не парить мозг о том, когда что то изменилось на сервере, он сообщит сам. Очень грязно реализуете, я бы сказал, просто в лоб

Comment: ну про возможность с вами спорить не буду, возможно это относится к скилу разработчика и я сейчас на первых ступенях. Но я оптимизировал код максимально по своим возможностям. Использовать сокеты увы не могу, так как сервер не мой. И соответственно устанавливать на него тоже ничего не могу.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Чтобы не морозить интерфейс, используйте для «тяжёлой» работы [web worker'ы](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Workers_API/Using_web_workers). Это отдельный от страницы браузера тред, исполняющий ваш JS.

Придётся немного переписать ваш код – чтобы общаться с Worker'ом через [`postMessage()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage) и событие `message`.

---

Чтобы оптимизировать по факту последовательные ajax запросы, попробуйте пере-использовать XMLHttpRequest объект. Возможно, при каждом запросе сейчас создаётся новый, занимая память, и при тысячах запросов память быстро уходит. См. поле `xhr` параметров [`jQuery.ajax()`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/).